# Error to validate connection before publish to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I imported the publish profile generated by Azure's App Service to Visual Studio. However, when I try to validate the connection, Visual Studio displays the error message . I'm trying to make a Web Deploy.

[image: error picture]

The error occurs after I click this button
[image: button]

Comment: What version of your visual studio is?

Comment: Hi Jason. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.9.1

Comment: I upgraded to version Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.9.2 and started to work again!

Comment: @LuizFelipe Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.